# how to select the max of COUNT(*) (SQL postgresql)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I switched from NOSQL to SQL and i can't find how to select the max of count(*)

i created users table, posts and comments.
i want to select TOP 10 users with the max of posts and max of comments

```
SELECT 
  fullname, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = users.id) 
    AS total_posts,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM comments WHERE comments.author_id = users.id)
    AS total_comments 
  FROM users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using SQL database require you to define the `JOIN` statement between the associated tables to get the referenced relationship data.

Since you require to get `TOP 10` user with most posts, using traditional approach with `LIMIT 10` will have problem when users have the same post count and should be considered the same rank. E.g: 4 people have 5 posts, 3 people have 6 posts..

To solve the same post count problem above, we will choose [RANK query](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/), this will treat people with the same post count as the same rank.

```
SELECT users.fullname, posting_rank_stats.total_posts, posting_rank_stats.posting_rank
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT author_id, total_posts, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY post_author_count.total_posts DESC) AS posting_rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_posts, author_id
        FROM posts
        GROUP BY author_id
    ) post_author_count
) posting_rank_stats
ON users.id = posting_rank_stats.author_id
-- we only want to search for top 10
WHERE posting_rank_stats.posting_rank <= 10;
```

Breaking to small pieces:

##### 1.Get post count for each user

First, we get the post count for each user, this require the `COUNT` function, and [GROUP BY](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) author_id

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_posts, author_id
FROM posts
GROUP BY author_id
```

##### 2. Calculating the rank of post count

Use the `RANK()` function to calculate the rank of the post. Ranking positition is determined by the highest number of `total_posts`

```
SELECT author_id, total_posts, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY post_author_count.total_posts DESC) AS posting_rank
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_posts, author_id
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY author_id
) post_author_count
```

##### 3. Wrap up

The last step is joining the `users` table with the `posting_rank_stats` table to get the result. Since we only want to get in the TOP 10 user with most post, so you will need to add the condition
`posting_rank_stats.posting_rank <= 10` in the `WHERE` clause

Apply the same concept to get comment rank also.

Here is the [db fiddle I created, combine both posting rank and commenting rank](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hDzSBgkHSbYAPe5TSWfoc8/0)

```
SELECT users.id , users.fullname, posting_rank_stats.posting_rank , posting_rank_stats.total_posts, commenting_rank_stats.comment_rank, commenting_rank_stats.total_comments
FROM users

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT author_id, total_posts, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY post_author_count.total_posts DESC) AS posting_rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_posts, author_id
        FROM posts
        GROUP BY author_id
    ) post_author_count 
) posting_rank_stats ON users.id = posting_rank_stats.author_id

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT author_id, total_comments, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY comment_author_count.total_comments DESC) AS comment_rank
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comments, author_id
        FROM comments
        GROUP BY author_id
    ) comment_author_count
) commenting_rank_stats ON users.id = commenting_rank_stats.author_id;
```

| id | fullname | posting_rank | total_posts | comment_rank | total_comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jackson | 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | Marry | 4 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | Josh | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | Harley | 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | Gordon | 4 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | Barney | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | Gman | 4 | 1 |  |  |
| 8 | Stephan | 3 | 2 |  |  |
| 9 | Lucy |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | Jordan |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | Bill |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | Rosh |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | Lee |  |  |  |  |

---

Comment: An alternative approach if you're using Postgres 13 is `FETCH FIRST WITH TIES`, see this [PostgreSQL 13: LIMIT … WITH TIES blog](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-13-limit-with-ties/) for example. Thanks to Jeremy suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`. For example:

```
select *
from (
  -- your query here
) x
order by total_posts desc
limit 10
```

Comment: This traditional `LIMIT` approach would not correct if we consider user with the same post count are in the same rank.

Comment: You could use `FETCH FIRST 10 WITH TIES` which was introduced in Postgres 12.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
   select u.fullname,count(p.posts) as totalposts, count(c.comments) as totalcomments
   from users u join posts p
   on u.id=p.author_id 
   join comment c on u.id=c.comments
   group by 1
   ORDER BY count(p.posts),count(c.comments) desc )  k
limit 10;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 